# Regex to find and replace any \ and / with the appropiate DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR

Tags: php, regex

Ok so I got this code to make sure the absolute directory's contain the appropiate directory separator, but I suck at regex and I made this very simple one which I tested on an online regex tester the regex seems to match the slashes in like: /aaa\bbbb/ just for example.

Maybe something in php goes wrong no idea.

```
preg_replace(array('[\/]','[\\]'),DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,PROJECT_DIR . '/resources/library/');
```

This now only returns the complete input string which is a directory with no slashes replaced.

Comment: You dont need a regex for some simple as that use str_replace twice like this... `str_replace("\", DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);  str_replace("/", DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a regex for simple character translations, there is a function do to that: [`strtr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php) *(that parses the string only once, that isn't the case when you use an array with `str_replace` or `preg_replace`)*

```
$str = strtr($str, '/\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
```

---

The reason your code doesn't work is that you need to escape the backslash twice to figure a literal backslash in a quoted string, once for the quoted string and once because the backslash is a special regex character: `\\\\`

Other thing since you use brackets as pattern delimiters, you don't have to escape the slash.

Comment: excuse, it's not about the question. i would understand what do you mean *that parses the string only once, that isn't the case when you use an array with str_replace or preg_replace* ? May be some example?

Comment: @splash58: When you use an array as first parameter with `preg_replace` or `str_replace` the string is entirely parsed once per items, dummy example: `str_replace(['a', 'c'], ['c', 'z'], 'abcd')` gives `zbzd` *(and not `cbzd` because there are two passes)*. `strtr('abcd', 'ac', 'cz')` or `strtr('abcd', ['a'=>'c', 'c'=>'z'])` return `cbzd` (one pass)

Comment: Cheers guys, strtr does the trick after a bit tweaking but next time I will do it like this and not waste time on the regex way. This is what I ended up with and it does the job as well as intended:

$str = str_replace(array('\\','/'), DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, PROJECT_DIR . '/resources/library/');